# best position for keyword in a Domain?

Tags: seo

I want to create a SEO domain name.

So at which position do our keyword should position?

Keyword is "Software"

1) Keyword at front
   Softwarefort. com

2) Keyword at Last
   FortSoftware. com

3) Keyword at Middle
   FortSoftwareBase. com

Which is best?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly keyword rich domain doesn't have the strength as it used to have.

But still, it matters.

I would encourage you to go with the name which reads well and customers can remember easily.

SEO angle should be secondary.